# Difference between Boolean operator symbols for AND and OR

Tags: notation, boolean-algebra

I feel like an idiot for asking this because I SHOULD know the answer, but what is the difference between the Boolean logic operators for AND and OR? For instance, I know AND can have the symbols $\&$, $\land$, and ·. I also know OR can have the symbols $|$, $\lor$, and $+$. I'm just not quite sure what the differences are. Put another way, when is one used over another? Help clarifying this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: Just saw that ^ can also be used for XOR, so now I'm quite confused.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. One set of symbols corresponds to and and the other to or. What is your question?

Comment: What are the differences? When is one used over another?

Comment: It depends on context, in logic one typically sees $\land, \lor$, in engineering one sees $\cdot, +$, in both software & hardware languages one sees $\&,|$.

Comment: Viewed abstractly it can be confusing to distinguish boolean operations AND vs. OR, because the roles they play are highly symmetric.  However to bring understanding into a firm grip, think about the real world meaning.  Would you rather be HEALTHY AND WEALTHY, or just HEALTHY OR WEALTHY?  A more mathematical way to express the meaning is with truth tables.  Write out the truth values for $p \land q$ (resp. $p \lor q$) when propositional variables $p,q$ are assigned values in {TRUE, FALSE}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols $\land$ and $\lor$ are [logical connectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective).  Their operands are statements that are either true or false.

The symbols $\cdot$ and $+$ are [switching circuit theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switching_circuit_theory) connectives.  Their operands are switches that are either open (infinite impedance) or closed (zero impedance).

Shannon (1938) noted that "the calculus of propositions" (or Huntington's (1904, 1933) "algebra of logic") had an equivalent interpretation in relay circuits.

Essentially, the two sets of symbols represent different things, but statements involving them are equivalent, so some people now use them interchangeably.

References:

- Huntington, E. V. (1904, July). Sets of independent postulates for the algebra of logic. *Transactions of the American Mathematical Society*, *5*(3), 288-309.
- Huntington, E. V. (1933, January). New sets of independent postulates for the
  algebra of logic, with special reference to Whitehead and Russell's Principia
  Mathematica. *Transactions of the American Mathematical Society*, *35*(1),
  274-304.
- Shannon, C. E. (1938, December). A symbolic analysis of relay and switching circuits.  *Transactions of the American Institute of Electrical Engineers*, *57*(12), 713-723.

Comment: $\cdot,+$ are used by digital design engineers and are exactly equivalent to the logic symbols.